# What is a technique for extracting the data pattern from experimental replicates?

Tags: machine-learning, pattern-recognition, signal-detection

I collect the data of air pollution over the year. The data is 2D where the first axis is discrete scale (mass of pollutants in integer; 50, 51, 52...) and another axis is continuous scale (intensity).

I want to extract the overrepresented pattern of these data. The masses that are found in mostly data should be in the real pattern, the masses that are appeared in some data should not be included. So I want to get the pattern of discrete scale with expected intensity. What technique can be used in this situation?

If the data is 3D (with another time dimension), is there some techniques to extract the real pattern out?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking about the data as 2D, think about it as a vector of real values $x\in [a,b]^N$ for $N$ discrete masses. You now have a sparse signal recovery problem where you want to minimize $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2N}\sum \|y_i-x\|_2^2 + \lambda \|x\|_1$$ This can be reformulated as the program:
$$\arg\!\min \|x\|_1 \textrm{  s.t.}\: \|\bar{y} -x\|_\infty \leq \sigma$$ which in turn can be expressed as a linear program in $2N$ variables. Solve this for multiple choices of $\lambda$ and choose the one that minimizes the mean squared error. The statistical model for this estimator is that $x$ is the mean of the multivariate normal $y_i$ with elementwise Laplace prior.